# Deck probability for five cards with different face values

Tags: probability

What is the probability of a five card hand where all values are different (where aces are 1s) and the highest value is 8?

This should include 32 cards total, with there being 8 different face values. But I'm not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid a misinterpretation of the question assume that there are $m\ge 5$ different face values (Aces, 2's, ...) with total $4m$ cards in the deck (32, 52, or whatever). Then

1. The probability of a five card hand where all values are different is

$$\frac{\binom{m}{5}4^5}{\binom{4m}{5}}$$

2. The probability of a five card hand where all values are different and these values are at most $5\le k\le m$ is

$$\frac{\binom{k}{5}4^5}{\binom{4m}{5}}$$

3. The probability of a five card hand where all values are different and the highest value is exactly $5\le k\le m$

$$\frac{\binom{k-1}{4}4^5}{\binom{4m}{5}}$$

Comment: Be careful.  There are only $32$ cards in the deck.

Answer (score 0):

The first card must be 8, if I understood correctly, so we must choose $1$ from $4$, i.e., there are 4 different choices. For the second card we have $32-4$ different outcomes, for the third we have $32-4\cdot 2$ valid cards, for the four $32-4\cdot 3$ and for the fifth $32- 4\cdot 4$.  And the total kind of hands are $32\cdot 31\cdot 30 \cdot29\cdot 28$. So

$$P=\frac{4}{(32)_5}\prod_{k=1}^{4} (32- 4k)$$

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, what does $(32)_5$ stand for ?

Comment: This is the falling factorial @trueblueanil.

Comment: Thanks, I think you should recheck your formulation.

Comment: I cant recheck formulation because the problem, as I said, is unclear @trueblueanil... I know what the others questions did but I dont know exactly what the OP is searching for...

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose 5 distinct ranks, and a suit for each
2. Divide by total ways for choosing any 5 cards

Pr = **$\dfrac{\binom{8}{5}4^5}{\binom{32}{5}}=\dfrac{256}{899}$**

Comment: The bottom would not be 52 choose 5?

Comment: The question clearly states "...32 cards total ..."